# AngularJS Route breaks on manual refresh

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

In the config method, I have some routes defined as follows:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$routeProvider.when('/', {
  ...
});

$routeProvider.when('/front', {
  ...
});

$routeProvider.when('/user/account', {
  ...
});
```

Everything works fine when navigating through the app using `<a href="">` tags. However, when I go to `/user/account` and manually refresh my browser, it pops the `/account` off the route and redirects me to `/user`, breaking the rendering in the process since there is no route defined for `/user`.

I noticed this does not happen when I configure the route to be `/account` only, but this is not fixing the real issue. So I set up the following catch-all (below the routes above) to log what's happening:

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({
  redirectTo: function() {
    console.log('bumped', arguments);

    return '/';
  }
});
```

and saw it was trying to match `/account` instead of `/user/account`. What is going on here?

I am on Angular 1.1.5. The server returns index.html appropriately on all requests (for HTML5 mode), so it seems like a client-side issue.

How can I configure this route correctly?

**EDIT**

Turns out this is a bug in 1.1.5 core.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2799

patched here

https://github.com/IgorMinar/angular.js/commit/2bc62ce98f893377bfd76ae211c8af027bb74c1d

Comment: I think you need [ui-router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/), [repo here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) here's an [article](http://txt.fliglio.com/2013/05/angularjs-state-management-with-ui-router/) about that.

Comment: @YahyaKACEM: I was looking at this earlier. Are you saying Angular doesn't support nested routes out of the box? (/user/account/:id vs /user/:somearea/:id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) which solved this issue.