# Should I migrate from ngRoute to ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, ngroute

I have a pretty extensive ngRoute router right now with around 15 different URL paths. The website I am working on displays pages with heavy data, lots of charts, etc. for a logged in user. My issue is that when I refresh the page, it will redirect me to my default page. I have tried adding these:

**app.config**

```
    if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });
    }
```

**< head> tag**

```
<base href="/"/>
```

**.htaccess**

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

This didn't work for me. It seems that switching to ui-router fixed this same issue for this guy in this link:  [AngularJS Route breaks on manual refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171230/angularjs-route-breaks-on-manual-refresh)

My questions:

1. Will ui-router really handle the manual refresh properly?
2. Is it worth it to migrate from ngRoute to ui-router or is it better to find the solution to manually refresh properly with ngRoute?

Answer (score 2):

I made the move, the migration was smooth, and it fixed my refresh issue! Feeling good about the switch.